# Delete a symbol in a string

Tags: prolog

I have a list of string. Sometimes a string can contain a particular symbol. For example if i have this list:

```
L=[dog,cat,tiger,,bear]
```

The string `"tiger,"` has the `","` concatenated with the word. How can I do to remove the `","` from `"tiger,"`?

Comment: The `L=[dog,cat,tiger,,bear]` term is not syntactically valid. Missing double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: Assuming you fix the syntax error in your list, what "particular symbols" are you looking to remove? And can they occur anywhere in the string, or just at the end?

Comment: I extract this list of terms from a text. But, sometimes, i find some incorrect terms like this example. This terms occur anywhere in the string.

Comment: The only error that occurs frequently is the "," near the term.

Comment: Can the "," occur anywhere in the term, or just at the end of the term?

Comment: the "," occur just at the end of the term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicate below, `fix_words(+WordsIn, -WordsOut)`, will "fix" the words (terms) in `WordsIn` yielding `WordsOut`. "fix" means that ANY character in the word that doesn't belong will be removed, regardless of where it occurs in the word (not just the end). This particular version rejects anything that's not alphabetic, but you can easily change it to anything you wish by changing the conditional check in `remove_baddies/2`.

```
fix_words([WordIn | WordsIn], [WordOut | WordsOut]) :-
    fix_word(WordIn, WordOut),
    fix_words(WordsIn, WordsOut).
fix_words([], []).

fix_word(WordIn, WordOut) :-
    atom_chars(WordIn, CharsIn),
    remove_baddies(CharsIn, CharsOut),
    atom_chars(WordOut, CharsOut).

remove_baddies([Char | CharsIn], [Char | CharsOut]) :-
    (Char @>= 'A', Char @=< 'Z';
    Char @>= 'a', Char @=< 'z'), !,
    remove_baddies(CharsIn, CharsOut).
remove_baddies([_ | CharsIn], CharsOut) :-
    remove_baddies(CharsIn, CharsOut).
remove_baddies([], []).
```

If you are just interested in removing commas, then the definition of `remove_baddies` could be:

```
remove_baddies([',' | CharsIn], CharsOut) :- !,
    remove_baddies(CharsIn, CharsOut).
remove_baddies([Char | CharsIn], [Char | CharsOut]) :-
    remove_baddies(CharsIn, CharsOut).
remove_baddies([], []).
```

The above only uses ISO predicates (`atom_chars/2`). SWI Prolog and GNU Prolog may offer some built-ins which make this a tiny bit simpler for determining character type (*e.g.*, SWI Prolog's `char_type/2` predicate).